Mapping google sheets cell to google drive and retreiving the link
I have a name in cell A2 eg;
A2="Giraffe"
i have a specific folder in which i have a file named "Giraffe"
Can google sheets find the file and get the link in the output cell B2

From your following reply,

I cant thank you enough for doing this for me Maybe its me who is making a mistake I am Going to post links of the google sheet and drive below I am getting some unknown error Google Sheet Link- docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/… Google Drive Folder Link - drive.google.com/drive/folders/…

When I saw your folder, I noticed that in your situation, no files are existing, only the folders are existing. In this case, please test the following script. In this script, both folders and the files are retrieved. When you use this script, please install the OnEdit triggert to installedOnEdit and put the folder name to column "A". By this, the folder link is put into column "B".
Sample script:
function installedOnEdit(e) {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.
  const folderId = "###"; // Please set your folder ID you want to search the files.

  const { range } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != sheetName || range.columnStart != 1 || range.rowStart == 1) return;

  const getFiles = (folder, obj = {}) => {
    if (folder) {
      const folderName = folder.getName();
      const folderLink = folder.getUrl();
      obj[folderName] = obj[folderName] ? [...obj[folderName], folderLink] : [folderLink];
      const files = folder.getFiles();
      while (files.hasNext()) {
        const f = files.next();
        const filename = f.getName();
        const link = f.getUrl();
        obj[filename] = obj[filename] ? [...obj[filename], link] : [link];
      }
      const subFolders = folder.getFolders();
      while (subFolders.hasNext()) {
        getFiles(subFolders.next(), obj);
      }
    }
    return obj;
  }

  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  const obj = getFiles(folder);
  const filename = range.getDisplayValue().trim();
  if (obj[filename]) {
    range.offset(0, 1).setValue(obj[filename]);
  }
}

If you want to retrieve only folders, please remove the following script from the above script.
const files = folder.getFiles();
while (files.hasNext()) {
  const f = files.next();
  const filename = f.getName();
  const link = f.getUrl();
  obj[filename] = obj[filename] ? [...obj[filename], link] : [link];
}


The first sample code gives me the answer File of ${filename} was not found. even if the file name is present and the folder ID is correct
The second sample code just completes its execution and no output is given in B2:B so it cant find the name in the drive

@Vansh Shah Now, by guessing your actual situation, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it. If my guess was not correct, I apologize again. At that time, please provide detailed information for correctly replicating the issue. By this, I would like to confirm it.

okay so,
I have a main folder called "Objects" in that folder I have 5 new folders
Animal 1
Animal 2
...
Animal 5
in every Animal folder there are folders which are named accordingly
my A2 = "Giraffe" so i want to fetch the link of the folder whose name is "Giraffe" from the folder "Animal 1".

@Vansh Shah Thank you for replying. From your reply, I could know that your situation has the folder including the subfolders. In this case, my added script can be used. Because in my added script, all subfolders in the folder are searched. Can you test my script?

Hi,
None of the script work I guess its okay I can just do it manually
Thank you so much for putting your efforts in this @Tanaike

@Vansh Shah Thank you for replying. About Hi, None of the script work I guess its okay I can just do it manually Thank you so much for putting your efforts in this @Tanaike, although I couldn't understand from your question, if you wanted to use my script as a custom function, unfortunately, in the current stage, this process cannot be used with the custom function because of the current specification of the custom function.

@Vansh Shah If you want to achieve your goal using a custom function, the current answer is that it's no. In this case, it is required to run the script with the manual operation or the OnEdit trigger. I apologize for this situation. And, I deeply apologize that I couldn't understand immediately your actual expected result from your showing question. I would like to study English more.

No I think you well understood my question @Tanaike I just think its not possible to do in google sheets without API I am getting this error
"Exception: You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFolderById. Required permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive) (line 22)."

@Vansh Shah Thank you for replying. Yes. In the current specification, this process cannot be used with the custom function. I deeply apologize for this situation. So, I proposed a method for manually executing the script. For example, as another approach, when a value is put into column "A", the file link can be automatically put to column "B" using the installable OnEdit trigger.

@Vansh Shah Now, I added one more sample script using the installable OnEdit trigger, please confirm it.

Hi @Tanaike I cant thank you enough for doing this for me
Maybe its me who is making a mistake I am Going to post links of the google sheet and drive below I am getting some unknown error
Google Sheet Link-
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RNS4QMuKSMqwVENGu6Bw9wzDA92jvOovRlOtLNPPeBY/edit#gid=0
Google Drive Folder Link -
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1itvowD790PutkahGBRRnvWkC6gbrhorM

@Vansh Shah Thank you for replying. From your reply, I could notice that in your situation, no files are existing, only the folders are existing. So, I updated my answer. Please confirm it. The new script retrieves both the folders and the files.

I CANNOT THANK YOU ENOUGH
It works THANK YOU SO MUCH @Tanaike

It is not a built-in functionality of any of google's APIs. However with some knowledge of a programming language. This can be trivially done with Google Sheets API and Google Drive API
Google Sheets API Reference
Google Drive API Reference
